# previous_posts_link not working in WordPress pagination

Tags: php, wordpress

when I click older entries (`next_posts_link`) it's working fine & go to the next page. but I don't see newer entries (`previous_posts_link`) so I can get back to the first page or previous page again. I'm using custom query to show some of my posts at home page. here is my snippet:

```
            <ul class="recipe-list">
                <?php
                    $home_rcp= $redux_imd['home_rcp'];

                    // Define custom query parameters
                    $rcpquery_args = array(
                    'cat' => $home_rcp,
                    'posts_per_page' => 4
                    );

                    // Get current page and append to custom query parameters array
                    $rcpquery_args['paged'] = get_query_var( 'page' ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : 1;

                    // Instantiate custom query
                    $rcpquery =  new WP_Query( $rcpquery_args );

                    // Pagination fix
                    $temp_query = $wp_query;
                    $wp_query   = NULL;
                    $wp_query   = $rcpquery;

                    while($rcpquery->have_posts()) : $rcpquery->the_post();
                ?>
                <li>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('recipe-thumb'); ?>
                    <div class="caption">
                        <div class="blur"></div>
                        <div class="caption-text">
                            <div class="post-title">
                                <h5><?php the_title() ?></h5>
                            </div>
                            <div class="recipe-home-meta">
                                <p>Posted  on <?php the_time('Y/m/d'); ?> By <?php the_author(); ?></p>
                            </div>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">SEE THIS RECIPE</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endwhile; 
                wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
                <div id="pagination">
                <?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries', $rcpquery->max_num_pages); ?>
                <?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;', $rcpquery->max_num_pages); ?>
                </div>
                <?php 
                // Reset main query object
                $wp_query = NULL;
                $wp_query = $temp_query;
                ?>
            </ul>
```

Comment: your code is working fine, make sure the post have the records with category you are sending to `WP_QUERY`

Comment: & how can I do it? I'm not good with php, hope you understand.

Comment: its not php problem , check the `posts`  in `wp-admin` and edit the `posts` to and check the  category is selected or not with the posts

Comment: yes I've already checked that. the category is selected.

Comment: what is the output of `$home_rcp` ?

Comment: category. I'm using redux framework to setup an option to the backend, so I can select the category from backend theme option panel.